# How to avoid using sapply() on user defined functions in R

Tags: r, function, statistics, vectorization, user-defined-functions

I am a beginner with R programming. Recently I wrote a user-defined function as follows:

```
foo <- function(x){
power <- 1:4
sum(x^power)
}
```

This function works fine when x is a single number. For example, when `x = 1`, the result is 4 and when `x = 10` the result is 11110. However, this function doesn't work with vectors. For example, when `x <- c(1, 10)`, the result is 10102 which is not what I want. My desire result is a vector such as `4 11110`. I know this problem can be solved by using `sapply()` on function or add a for-loop inside the function, but I think there might be another way to rewrite the function without using loops or "apply" functions. I have tried different ways to rewrite the function but nothing works, can somebody help me to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, a simple and more straightforward approach is to rewrite `foo` function like below

```
foo <- function(x) {
  power <- 1:4
  ifelse(x==1,max(power),x*(x**(max(power))-1)/(x-1))
}
```

which gives

```
> foo(c(1,10))
[1]     4 11110
```

Comment: This runs 3.1x faster than my solution, and is much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to avoid any kind of implicit or explicit loop since `power` is a vector and you are passing `x` to it which is another vector.

Here are few options :

1. Your best bet is `sapply` (which you have already figured out).

```
sapply(c(1, 10), foo)
#[1]     4 11110
```

2. Another way is to use `Vectorize` where you cannot "see" the loop but it still loop beneath as it is a wrapper to `mapply`.

```
Vectorize(foo)(c(1, 10))
#[1]     4 11110
```

3. Using `outer` :

```
foo <- function(x){
  power <- 1:4
  rowSums(outer(x, power, `^`))
}
foo(c(1, 10))
#[1]     4 11110
```

and obviously you can write a simple `for` loop as well and pass `c(1, 10)` to it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```r
foo <- function(x, power = 1:4){
  
  ind <- 1 + seq_along(power)
  power <- matrix(rep(power, length(x)), nrow = length(x), byrow = T)
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  
  m <- cbind(x, power)
  m <- m[, 1]^m[, ind]
  v <- rowSums(m)
  
  return(v)
  
}

foo(x = c(1, 10))
## [1]     4 11110
```

Runs about 8.5x faster than using `sapply(x foo)` (when `foo` is a vector of length == 1,000,000). It's a bit late here, so I don't know whether you could optimise the internals a little better.